# jquery .remove() Unexpected '​'. error

Tags: javascript, jquery, gulp

Hi I am running gulp and getting this error on my command line.

`line 178   col 48  Unexpected '​'.`

The line is this:

```
 jQuery(".wpdf_document_icon");​
```

The .remove() works as it should but I don't know why there is an error ?

**EDIT.**

Establised that is a ZERO WIDTH SPACE error thanks to @Xufox.
Now wondering how I get rid of this?

**UPDATE/SOLVED**.

Deleted the line/s and retyped it - this has solved the issue - thanks to @Pointy

Comment: After the `;` there’s a `ZERO WIDTH SPACE`. It’s actually in the error message as well.

Comment: Thanks, now wondering how I get rid of this? cheers

Comment: Huh? Just remove the space from your code. The space is not in your string. This has nothing to do with your string, only with your code. `str.replace(/\u200B/g,'');` doesn’t even remove anything from any string.

Comment: Hmm ok, apologies. I have deleted any space from next to the .remove(); but the same thing is happening?

Comment: The space is still there, right _after the `;`_.

Comment: Delete the entire line and retype it. Do not do it by cutting and pasting.

Comment: I bump up the next line of code right next to ; but then the error occurs at the end of that line..?

Comment: Look this is an extremely simple problem. You probably pasted that code in from someplace. Delete everything in the vicinity and type it all back in by hand.

Comment: Ah ok I have done suggestion by Pointy and have deleted and retyped  - this has solved the problem. Thanks!